# org-mode ignoring category filter on export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'm trying to create a "calendar only" view of my org-mode agenda -- only headlines that have a "cal" category. The `org-agenda-custom-commands` below (the first block) works brilliantly for viewing within emacs, but the filter doesn't work when I `C-a a e` to export. That is, `calendar.txt` ends up with headlines from all categories, instead of only "cal" categories.

Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding something?

```
;; custom agenda views
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands

      ;; bug?: exporting to calendar ignores my category filter, but
      ;; it works when I view in emacs
      '(("c" "Calendar only" agenda ""
         ((org-agenda-category-filter-preset '("+cal"))
          (org-agenda-span 'week)
          (org-agenda-use-time-grid nil))
         ("~/Dropbox/wiki/calendar.txt"))

        ;; the default block view that comes with org mode
        ("n" "Agenda and all TODO's"
         ((agenda "" nil)
          (alltodo "" nil))
         nil
         ("~/Dropbox/wiki/agenda.txt"))))
```

Comment: @Melioratus regarding your proposed edit. There isn't yet a preferred format, see http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/15/should-we-use-the-kbd-tag-or-not and http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/160/may-we-settle-on-using-backticks-for-key-descriptions. I think both `C-a a e` or <kbd>C-a a e</kbd> are okay, but what you are proposing, <kbd>C-a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> is way to noisy and doesn't look at all like what you would get inside Emacs.